# Changing ChartData of a PowerPoint Chart with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, interop, powerpoint

I have a `PowerPoint Presentation` with a `barchart`. Now I want to change the data of this chart. I have a class (that works) where I already have the PowerPoint Slide object. My code is:

```
Sub ChangeData(byval sldNr as integer, ChartName as String, byval testValue as Integer)

_pptSld = _pptPre.Slides(sldNr)

    Dim oWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim oWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Try
        oWorkBook = CType(_pptSld.Shapes(ChartName).Chart.ChartData.Workbook, Excel.Workbook)
        oWorkSheet = CType(oWorkBook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

        With oWorkSheet
            .Range("B2").Value = testValue
    Catch ex As Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
end sub
```

I get the Error `hresulte e_fail-error` in the line

```
oWorkBook = CType(_pptSld.Shapes(ChartName).Chart.ChartData.Workbook, Excel.Workbook)
```

The error is very general and I just cannot see what is wrong here. In other functions I already use _pptSld so there is nothing wrong. Would be great if anyone could help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer by myself. First you have to activate the `ChartData Object` and second you have to refresh the datasource after importing the data to updata the sheet.

Her is what works:

```
         _pptSld = _pptPre.Slides(2)
        _pptChar = _pptSld.Shapes(2).Chart
        _pptChartData = _pptChar.ChartData
        _pptChartData.Activate()

        oWorkBook = CType(_pptSld.Shapes(2).Chart.ChartData.Workbook, Excel.Workbook)
        oWorkSheet = CType(oWorkBook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

        With oWorkSheet
            .Range("B2").Value = 30
            _pptChar.Refresh()
        End With

        oWorkBook.Close()
```

Comment: If you loop this in a function you have to set Threading.Thread.Sleep(50) or a bit lower. Otherwise the application crashes do to overlapping processes since the refresh needs a bit of time.